# Should i get expire time After cancel Subscription without Google API?

Tags: android, subscription, in-app

Should i get expire time  After cancel Subscription without Google API?

```
{
    "orderId": "1299974343434705758.13875232327338313",
    "packageName": "com.test.99",
    "productId": "test_99",
    "purchaseTime": 1423213027496,
    "purchaseState": 0,
    "purchaseToken": "noimmjfcnmafdojafpjhfmde.AO-J1OxBkjEDO5O8LwoAt71J82oc7vPXUZEz74MfRgIE3G-X013YC9yJKtHrNgllQsgSkIlOdMVDuPteiyx8hRBo_USP",
    "autoRenewing": true
}
```

If "purchaseState": 1 but its expire or not how i can check?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [User billing](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#administering) section of the Android docs...

> With In-app Billing Version 3, the failed or expired subscription is
>   no longer returned when you call `getPurchases`.